# Resetear Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-11.2

Como bien dice el título. ¿Cómo puedo dejar a Netbeans 11.2 con sus configuraciones originales? Probé con reinstalarlo pero hasta seguía el tema oscuro instalado, también reinstalé el JDK (perdonad mi ignorancia) y no ha cambiado nada. En internet solo encuentro como cambiar de color el tema.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Cuando lo desinstalas te borraste las carpetas que este deja a veces en archivos de programa?

Comment: Sí. Lo hice cuando lo reinstalé por tercera vez. Es posible que se me haya quedado una carpeta, pero según el buscador de Windows no había nada que coincidiera con Netbeans,

Comment: Me parece que en la carpeta de usuarios, luego en tu usuario y una que se llama app data ojo que están ocultas, checa si por ahí quedó algo

Comment: Sí, ahí quedaban más carpetas y funcionó. Ha sido un alivio. ¡Muchas gracias!